# Iterate over children and setting their properties in react

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I am using a library which has this `Card` components. They are basically clickable cards. I want something like `CardGroup` component. By that, what I mean is if one card is selected, other cards in the group will get deselected automatically(like radio button group). I intend `CardGroup` to wrap all the `Card`s around something like this:

```
<CardGroup>
  <Card>
  ...
  </Card>
  <Card>
  ...
  </Card>
</CardGroup>
```

And in `CardGroup` I want to iterate over `this.props.children` and set their properties selected to `true` or `false`. How should I make this component. I tried `React.Children.forEach` to iterate over childs and select its property but it is not writable. Is there any other way to modify childs? I also want to know if it is a common practice to modify childs in this way and if it has any solution.

Answer (score 1):

Usual way to do this is to hold your card data in an array in your state including e.g. an `id` for each `Card`. Use this data to render your `Card`s and handle the state updating.

So something like this (pseudo-code):

```
onCardSelect = id => {
    // loop through your cards in your state and update isSelected according
    // to your id
}

<CardGroup>
  {this.state.cards.map(card=>
    <Card onClick={card.id => this.onCardSelect(cardId)}>
     </Card>
   )
  }
</CardGroup>
```

Comment: And my `CardGroup` will just render {this.props.children} ?

Comment: children prop is used to render components from further up the tree. If you create your Cards further up and pass them as children then you'll have to move your state and onCardSelect logic up to the same location

Comment: Hmm...as far as I understand, You are suggesting me to just remove the `CardGroup` component and manage the state in my current component? because now `CardGroup` doesn't have any logic? If I wanted to keep `CardGroup`(because it can be re-usable) can you suggest me how to modify the childrens?

Comment: Why do you need to pass children at all?

Comment: I want to make a reusable `CardGroup` component for re-use. If I implement it your way, what do I write in `CardGroup` component? I don't think it will have any use.

Comment: Well it's up to you, but you should to hold your state and deal with your updates at the same place in your tree. So if your card data is coming from a parent, your onCardSelect update logic should be there too.